# How can I connect vs code to my subdomain

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, vs-code

I am new in learning lwr & lwc. I have installed VS Code, salesforce extension pack inside VS code, &  Salesforce CLI .

On salesforce side I created a new site/subdomain in my sandbox by >Feature settings>Digital Experiences>New

When I try to authorize my new project in VS Code from the command sfdx authorize an org>Custom domain with my subdomain it authorizes my sandbox parent and not the subdomain meaning I can see custom components I made on my sandbox editor but if I try editing page on subdomain I dont see my custom componets.

TL/DR/DU(didn't understand):
How can I connect vs code to my subdomain

Comment: I want to make sure I understand your question. You want to edit your Community/Experience site right? You will still want to use the Experience Builder in the org, VS Code won't give you any additional tooling there. If you want your LWCs to be available for your experience site, then the LWC needs to configured to be available: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_config_for_community_builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your components need to be [enabled for the Experience Builder](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_config_for_community_builder). Once you do this, your custom components will appear in the Experience Builder. There's no need to connect to any specific subdomain within your Sandbox.